# javascript thumb image hover change to larger image with different source

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a webpage with a larger image and below that some thumbnails. I got some code from stackoverflow to make hovering over the thumbnail alter the main image.

```
var largeImage = $("#largeImage");
$(".image-list img").hover(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#largeImage").attr("src",src);
});
```

However, the examples I have seen use the source of the thumbnail. As I dont want to compress the thumbnail I have small thumnails eg  ./images/car-108x72.png

I also have larger versions eg ./images/car-468x311.png

Is there a way to change the source (src) within the javapart to use the larger image? There  are multiple thumbnails and larger versions so it needs to be dynamic instead of a static url.

Comment: On the thumbnail `<img>` tag, you could add a `data-large` parameter, and use that instead. so `<img src="thumbnaail.png" data-large="some-larage-image-here.png">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Actually, @NickR's solution is better than mine as long as your web page is HTML5. Use the `data-large` attribute for your img tags.

e.g.: `<img src="thumbnail.png" data-large="some-large-image-here.png">`

Then access the large image using:

```
 var largeImage = $("#largeImage");
 $(".image-list img").hover(function(){
 var src = $(this).attr("data-large");
 $("#largeImage").attr("src",src);
```

Original answer:

Change your code to:

```
 var largeImage = $("#largeImage");
 $(".image-list img").hover(function(){
 var src = $(this).attr("src");
 src = src.replace("108x72","468x311");
 $("#largeImage").attr("src",src);
```

Answer (score 0):

add your thumb image tag additional tag just as `large_img_src`

```
<img src="img1.png" larg_img_src="large_img1.png">
<img src="img2.png" larg_img_src="large_img2.png">
<img src="img3.png" larg_img_src="large_img3.png">
```

now apply jquery like this

```
var largeImage = $("#largeImage");
$(".image-list img").hover(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr("larg_img_src");
    $("#largeImage").attr("src",src);
});
```